# Download results in amazon braket

Tags: amazon-braket

Suppose I have the simple circuit

```
bell = Circuit().h(0).cnot(control=0, target=1)
```

and I am running it in a notebook inside AWS. How can I download the results to my local pc when

1. I use the `LocalSimulator()`.
2. An IonQ or a Rigetti device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run on an IonQ or Rigetti device (or any other QPU or AWS-managed simulator) your results are stored in the S3 bucket/folder you specified at runtime:

```
# the name of the bucket
my_bucket = "example-bucket"
# the name of the folder in the bucket
my_prefix = "simulation-output"
s3_folder = (my_bucket, my_prefix)

# cloud-based managed simulator/QPU to run your circuit
device = AwsDevice('arn:aws:braket:::device/qpu/ionq/ionQdevice')

# execute the circuit
task = device.run(bell, s3_folder, shots=100)
```

To download your results, navigate to that S3 bucket/folder, click on `results.json`, and then in the upper right corner, you will see a `Download` button.

The results of runs using the local simulator are not stored in S3, or written to any file:

```
device = LocalSimulator()
task = device.run(bell, shots=100)
```

However, if you were so inclined, you could recreate the same behavior by doing a `json.dump` of the local quantum task result into a local file, and then use the `upload_to_s3` or `upload_local_data` method from the `braket.aws.AwsSession` module.

For example, if you run

```
result = task.result()
```

followed by

```
import json

with open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(str(result), f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

a file `result.json` would be created in your working directory. In the AWS Braket notebook filesystem, the full path would be `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/result.json`. Clicking the jupyter icon in the top left corner will take you back to the filesystem GUI, where you will see the results file present. Back in the notebook, you can then use the previously mentioned functions from the [AwsSession module](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python/blob/11ade6896a0e449a383713ce2fc1f74a06c463e9/src/braket/aws/aws_session.py) to upload this file to S3.

To reiterate, the results of circuits run using the `LocalSimulator` are not automatically sent to S3. The procedure that I've described is just one of many ways that you can explicitly write the results into a file, and manually upload to S3. This is possible both from jupyter on your local computer, and from inside of your AWS Braket notebook instance, and works effectively the same way.

Comment: I don't understand the last part, but I think I had in mind something different. If you run in `LocalSimulator` in the cloud (not in e.g. in a laptop), how do you do to send the results to the s3 bucket?

Comment: @user2820579 Let me know if the edits I made help, or if it's still unclear

Comment: @user2820579 Why would you want to run the `LocalSimulator` in the cloud when you can use `aws_sv1_simulator`, which will send results to the bucket?

Comment: SIMPLE,  `sv1` is not free!